# Error while compling GWT (Sencha Framework) Project

Tags: gwt, extjs, gxt

I am developing a simple web application. I am using sencha(gxt) framework to display chart to user.

When I am compiling the project, I am getting following errors.

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/E:/eclipse%20Workspace/Chart_Demo/src/com/project/client/Chart_Demo.java'
         [ERROR] Line 74: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.chart.client.chart.Chart<M>; did you forget to inherit a required module?

[ERROR] Line 78: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.chart.client.draw.Gradient; did you forget to inherit a required module?

[ERROR] Line 79: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.chart.client.draw.RGB; did you forget to inherit a required module?

[ERROR] Line 84: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.chart.client.chart.axis.CategoryAxis<M,V>; did you forget to inherit a required module?

[ERROR] Line 85: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.chart.client.chart.Chart<M>.Position; did you forget to inherit a required module?

[ERROR] Line 87: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.chart.client.draw.sprite.TextSprite; did you forget to inherit a required module?

[ERROR] Line 102: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.chart.client.chart.series.BarSeries<M>; did you forget to inherit a required module?


[ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.project.client.Chart_Demo'
         [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
         [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read from byte cache
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

wilome is right. The `<inherits>`-tags in the module descriptor are missing.

But it looks like Ranjeet is using GXT 3.

In this case it schould be:

```
<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'/>
<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.chart.Chart' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit the GXT modules in your main module (yourapp.gwt.xml)

```
<inherits name="com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT" />
<inherits name="com.extjs.gxt.themes.Themes" />
<inherits name="com.extjs.gxt.charts.Chart" />
```